# ¿Como ocultar una columna de un DataGridView si el CheckBox esta en su propiedad OnChecked y mostrarla si esta en su propiedad Checked en C#?

Tags: c#, msql

Muy buenas  Compañer@s. Tengo una consulta en la cual necesito su ayuda.
tengo un proyecto en C# el cual tiene una vista para registrar datos, estos se reflejan o se muestran en un DataGrid la consulta:

```
Select * from Detalle_formas_pago
```

Con las siguientes columnas: id, fecha, nombre_forma_de_pago y valor. También tengo un panel con unos CheckBox con el nombre de cada columna y un botón Aplicar, la idea es que al hacer Onchecked sobre uno de estos y al pinchar el botón aplicar este me oculte la columna que marque y solo muestre las que no estén marcadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Daniel podrías decirme si la respuesta dada te resultó útil y en caso de que lo haya sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Comment: hola buena tarde compañero, tu respuesta es satisfactoria, pero tengo un inconveniente en la ejecución ya que al marcar los dos primeros check es decir Código y fecha y al dar en aplicar, no me oculta ninguna columna, pero al marcar el 3 que es almacén entonces es cuando me oculta el código, en la propiedad Tag asigne de 0 a 7 como me indicaste según el orden del índice de las columnas.

Comment: Y también no me permite volver a mostrar las columnas al desmarcar los check...

Comment: Revisa bien los índices de las columnas, hay un errorcito por ahí, estás cerquita de resolverlo

Comment: Si ya los validé y mis primeras 2 columnas son un editar y eliminar así que mi índice número 2, el índice 3 sería para fechas sería para el código y así sucesivamente para los demás... pero sigo con la novedad de volver a mostrar las columnas. estoy intentando validar con un if que si la columna esta oculta me la muestre y si esta visible me la oculte... pero me genera que si marco 1 solo check y después quiero marcar otro me va a ocultar el que esta visible y el oculto me lo mostrar.... creo que hay una mejor forma...

Comment: Tu leíste la actualización de mi respuesta?

Comment: Hola si claro, pero me genera el siguiente error: El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección...

Comment: Revisa bien los índices de tus columnas, el error está por ahí, ese código funciona bien

Comment: Los índices los tengo bien, pues con el fragmento de código anterior me funciona a la perfección el único problema es que debería seleccionar los que deseo ocultar en una sola acción al aplicar....

Comment: socio, revisa bien, mi codigo hace eso, hay algo que no estas haciendo bien o no estas explicandolo bien, porfavor revisa bien, ponle ganas y empeño

Comment: Acabo de probar mi codigo y funciona perfecto, estas haciendo algo mal tu, te repito revisa bien

Comment: Ya revisé amigo... igual te agradezco la ayuda, me sirvió para lo que quería... igual te hare caso y verificare de nuevo y si algo te comento....

Comment: Bueno si la respuesta resolvió tú problema no olvides marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código que tienes puesto en el botón Aplicar

Comment: Amigo listo ya validé los índices están bien en el orden, pero con el anterior código que me pasaste primer, me permite no agregar los dos índices de eliminar y editar que tengo, pero para el código actualizado si me obliga a agregarlos al panel... de esta manera si logre ocultar los que están marcados y volver a mostrar los que estén ocultos al desmarcar el checkBox.... muchas gracias

Comment: Te lo dije, que leyeras la actualizacion de mi respuesta, que funcionaba perfecto, ahora por favor si mi respuesta te fue util no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Daniel en stackoverflow se agradece marcando la respuesta como aceptada, esto se te ha explicado varias veces y sigues haciendo caso omiso, te estás creando un mal precedente en la comunidad, lo cual puede influir a la hora de darte una respuesta, si te ganas un mal precedente en la comunidad es muy probable que tus preguntas queden sin respuestas y hasta cerradas sino te esfuerzas por redactarlas mejor, así que te pido que valores el tiempo que otros te dedican y aceptes las respuestas que se te dan, gracias y feliz navidad

Comment: Hola, la Comunidad agradeceria que si alguna de las respuestas dadas en tu pregunta es correcta o te ayudo a solucionar tu problema, marques estas como respondida, adicional esto te dara resputacion como usuario y en tu cuenta.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando presiones el **botón Aplicar** guarda en una **lista de enteros** los índices de las columnas que harías invisibles atendiendo a los **CheckBox** que seleccionaste, te recomiendo que a la **propiedad Tag** de cada **CheckBox** le des el valor del índice que tiene la columna que representa dentro del **DataGridView**, siguiendo tu ejemplo la **columna código** tiene como **índice de columna** el valor **0**, **Fecha** tiene el valor **1** y así sucesivamente, por tanto la **propiedad Tag** del **CheckBox Codigo** tendría el valor **0**, la **propiedad Tag** del **CheckBox Fecha** el valor **1** y así sucesivamente, esto hará que el código sea más simple:

```
private void Aplicar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var columnas = panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                                 .Where(c => c.Checked)
                                 .Select(c => Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag)).ToList();

    foreach (var c in columnas)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[c].Visible = false;  
    }
}
```

En este código lo que haces es guardar en la **variable columna** los **Tag** de los **CheckBox** dentro del **Panel** que están marcados. Posteriormente haces un **ciclo foreach** que recorra esta lista y haga invisible las columnas indicadas de acuerdo al valor del **Tag** especificado.

Aquí yo hago uso de **Linq** por tanto debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

## **Actualización:**

Atendiendo el correcto análisis de @Yussef mejoro mi respuesta:

```
private void Aplicar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var columnas = panel.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();

    foreach (var c in columnas)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag)].Visible = !c.Checked;
    }
}
```